Django Error: "'type' object is not iterable"
i'm a Django beginner and want to write a website for my friend who works as a painter.
i wanted to write a rest-api so i can access the models in my frontend (which i didnt implement yet).
when i try to call the subdomain for a model i wrote i get the error "'type' object is not iterable".
i wanted to make it possible for users that are registered to leave a feedback, so i wrote a class Feedback. I also implemented a FeedbackSerializer and a FeedbackView.
i was trying to use chatgpt but that was of no help. stackoverflow also didnt have any similar errors like the one that occured to me.
so i came here for help.
maybe you guys can help me out.
here's what i came up with so far:
# api/models.py
class Feedback(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)
    feedback = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(
        upload_to="image", default="default/default-user.jpg", null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)], null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Feedback, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

# api/serializers.py
class FeedbackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = api_models.Feedback
        fields = "__all__"

# api/views.py
class FeedbackView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = api_serializer.FeedbackSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        feedback_id = self.kwargs["feedback_id"]
        try:
            feedback = api_models.Feedback.objects.get(id=feedback_id)
        except api_models.Feedback.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Feedback not found.")
        return feedback

# api/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("feedback/<feedback_id>/", api_views.FeedbackView.as_view()),
]

full traceback:
TypeError at /api/v1/feedback/1/
'type' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/feedback/1/
Django Version: 5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'type' object is not iterable
Exception Location: /home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 272, in get_authenticators
Raised during:  api.views.FeedbackDetailView
Python Executable:  /home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.11.6
Python Path:    
['/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend',
 '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.11',
 '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
 '/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 14 Aug 2024 12:24:10 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 197, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py, line 65, in _view_wrapper
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 104, in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 492, in dispatch
        request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 394, in initialize_request
            authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
/home/jakob-adler/webdev/malergeschaeft_ernst/malergeschaeft_ernst/backend/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 272, in get_authenticators
        return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

 

i was expecting that i could just call subdomain /feedback/1/ and it would show me an API view for each feedback.
i created a feedback through the admin-page but somehow it doesnt work as expected

the error indicates that there is no instance (object) to iterate from. Looking at your views, Urls, and serializer (forms), I don't see an error. However, I didn't see you overriding any instance/field in the model, so the save() method is an overkill, kindly remove it. Also ensure that you go through your imports and that they are correct. One more thing please, have you created any User/feedback in your model either using Admin panel or the Django shell? So, that you can easily fetch the data from the API you are calling.

Share the full traceback.

thanks for replying. i added the traceback now. hope this help? cause i can't find the error and i'm quite desperate right now :D
i added the feedback and user objects through the admin-page.

The traceback you added is still not complete. Something caused DRF to invoke get_authenticators(). Share the full error traceback.

i hope now it is complete or is it necessary to provide the request information as well?
sadly i dont know how to format this properly since i'm just copying and pasting.

Share your settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'].

share details error logs

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",),
}
this is the REST_FRAMEWORK dictionary.

Ohh! then the answer I posted doesn’t work for you.

Mhm, i'm not quite sure, what i did wrong to be honest

Have you solved this? I’d love to take a dive. If you can, share a repo containing a [mre] that can reproduce this exactly. If you have solved this, I’d love to hear what the issue was all along.

When using DRF’s authentication mechanisms, the settings below must be a Python Iterable else get_authenticators() will not be able to setup your authentication procedure.
assert isinstance(settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'], collections.abc.Iterable)
If you enclose an AUTHENTICATION_CLASS in parentheses such as:
settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'] = (•••)
It is not a one element tuple like you might expect but is simply considered to be just another Python variable. A one element tuple is a literal such as: (•••,). Hence the correct code ought to be:
settings.REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'] = (•••,)
My recommendation is usually to use list over tuple whenever one can.
